# EXCEL return range of values based on criteria

Tags: excel, function, formula, lookup

I have a VBA function that I would like to pass a custom range of data (As opposed to a full table column range) only when certain criteria within that table is met.  For example:

```
          Table_1                            Table_2
    A        B         C                A          B
1 Policy    Data     Status     |   1 Policy    Function
  --------------------------    |     -------------------
2   AA      25      approved    |   2   AA      [25, 35]
3   AA      19      unapproved  |   3   BB      [16]
4   BB      16      approved    |
5   CC      27      approved    |
6   CC      30      unapproved  |
7   AA      35      approved
```

In Table2, cell B2, I would like to return a range of all `Data` values from Table1 where `Policy = AA` and `Status = approved`. Subsequently, in cell B3 a range of values where `Policy = BB` and `Status = approved` etc..

Is this possible with a formula?

Comment: That depends, do you already have the unique list of Policies in the second table and are you using Office 365 Excel?

Comment: I am using O365 Excel, and Table2 has non-unique list of policies (which is intended, there will be multiple AA and BB rows - that should return that same ranges)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel or later you can use TEXTJOIN as an Array Formula:

```
="[" & TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(($A$2:$A$7=F2)*($C$2:$C$7="approved"),$B$2:$B$7,"")) & "]"
```

Being an Array Formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel or later, here is a UDF that will do what you want:

```
Function TEXTJOINIFS(rng As Range, delim As String, ParamArray arr() As Variant)
    Dim rngarr As Variant
    rngarr = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Value

    Dim condArr() As Boolean
    ReDim condArr(1 To Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Rows.Count) As Boolean


    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2
        Dim colArr() As Variant
        colArr = Intersect(arr(i), arr(i).Parent.UsedRange).Value
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(colArr, 1) To UBound(colArr, 1)

            If Not condArr(j) Then
                Dim charind As Long
                charind = Application.Max(InStr(arr(i + 1), ">"), InStr(arr(i + 1), "<"), InStr(arr(i + 1), "="))
                Dim opprnd As String
                If charind = 0 Then
                    opprnd = "="
                Else
                    opprnd = Left(arr(i + 1), charind)
                End If
                Dim t As String
                t = """" & colArr(j, 1) & """" & opprnd & """" & Mid(arr(i + 1), charind + 1) & """"
                If Not Application.Evaluate(t) Then condArr(j) = True
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = LBound(rngarr, 1) To UBound(rngarr, 1)
        If Not condArr(i) Then
            TEXTJOINIFS = TEXTJOINIFS & rngarr(i, 1) & delim
        End If
    Next i

    TEXTJOINIFS = Left(TEXTJOINIFS, Len(TEXTJOINIFS) - Len(delim))

End Function
```

You would call it similar to SUMIFS:

```
=TEXTJOINIFS(B:B,",",A:A,F2,C:C,"approved")
```

It only works with columns not rows.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: My mistake, I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 excel, and unfortunately do not have the TEXTJOIN function

Comment: @Sean then vba is the only way to go.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write this up in VBA, much appreciated!