# Outputting multiple VLookup values in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking to create a formula which outputs numerous values associated with an ID into just one cell. The number of values varies e.g. one ID may have 3 values associated with it, another may have just 1.

I know that if I were using VBA, I could use a loop to output all the values but I'm using just Excel in this example. All I have so far is a simple lookup which outputs just one value

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'Customer Tape'!A:B,2,0)
```

(B2 is the cell; for Customer Tape column A is the ID, column B is the value)

Is there any way to get all of the values associated with the ID (e.g. values on other rows) and output it to the same cell?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have/need to support?

Comment: Using Excel 2013

Comment: You'll need code then, if it has to be a formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With older versions it is either vba or a helper column.

With the helper column put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=B2&IFERROR(","&VLOOKUP(A2,A3:C$1040000,3,FALSE),"")
```

[image]

Then you can use a normal VLOOKUP to return just the first result from column C:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,A:C,3,FALSE)
```

[image]

If you want a vba version then see here:

[EXCEL return range of values based on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582741/excel-return-range-of-values-based-on-criteria)

or here:

[Merge values of column B based on common values on column A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a)

Or here:

[TextJoin UDF For Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843881/textjoin-udf-for-excel-2013)

---

For Office 365 Excel no helper column needed:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(B:B,A:A=E2,""))
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Although I'm entering your formula and only getting one value - even though there are clearly more identical values in the next few lines.

Comment: It will only show one value till you fill the whole column with the formula.  It is dependent on the output of the formula below.

Comment: Yes I've dragged the formula down and still only getting the one value per ID.

Comment: please post a link to a picture of the sheet showing the formula in the first cell.  As you can see it works for me.

Comment: Sure, question updated to include columns A, B & C, followed by the formula for Cell C2.

Comment: I need to see the column letters and row numbers and the cell in which the formula is put or the formula means nothing.

Comment: Updated to include the above

Comment: `B$2:C$88` should be `A3:C$88`