# Excel Transpose and or Merge cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, merge, pivot, transpose

I have an excel list of school courses that needs to be transposed/merged, the data looks like this

[image]

I want it to look like this

[image: 6001100 Elem Education 6002100 English, ESE Support Facilitator, ESE Teacher,Math 6004100 Elem Education]

Is this possible without VBA?

Comment: yes, but depending on which version of Excel you have will determine if you need helper columns or not.

Comment: see here for the helper column route: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486496/outputting-multiple-vlookup-values-in-excel/68487015#68487015

Comment: @ScottCraner do you know if there is a formula for completing this? I thought TEXTJOIN would work but there are different number of courses tied to the course number, i.e. 3 courses for 6002100 but 1 for the other 2 course codes.

Comment: Like I said depending on your version.  What version do you have?

Comment: @ScottCraner 2016 on my laptop, 2019 on my desktop

Comment: 2016 does not have TEXTJOIN, so you will need to do the helper column like the link I showed.

Answer (score 4):

With Office 365 we can use UNIQUE to get a list of unique Row Labels:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A9)
```

With 2019 one would have to get the Unique list with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$9)/(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$9)=0),1)),"")
```

Then use TEXTJOIN to do the concatenation:

```
=E2&" " &TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(B:B,A:A=E2,""))
```

[image]

With 2016 use the formula for the unique list from 2019 and then use the method here: [Outputting multiple VLookup values in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486496/outputting-multiple-vlookup-values-in-excel/68487015#68487015)

To use a helper column then use:

```
 =E2&" "&VLOOKUP(E2,A:C,3,FALSE)
```

to return the desired value:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With Excel 365. D2:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(A$2:A$8),ROW(A1))&" "&TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(B:B,A:A=INDEX(UNIQUE(A$2:A$8),ROW(A1))))
```

[image]

or older version: Format Column A using this format text. E2：

```
=D2&SUBSTITUTE(PHONETIC(OFFSET(A$1,MATCH(D2,A:A,)-1,,COUNTIF(A:A,D2),2)),D2," ")
```

[image]

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.This is for your reference only.